# From single to multindex dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, dataframe, geopandas

I have a geodataframe like this:

```
Out[7]: 
                                               geometry
FID                                                    
0     POLYGON ((7.662965420348624 45.05600185397847,...
1     POLYGON ((7.665210146514162 45.05607590098681,...
2     POLYGON ((7.663353281768154 45.05601113630467,...
3     POLYGON ((7.660229137844505 45.0570570693801, ...
```

and I want to add another index, which is a time series index like this:

```
Out[10]: 
DatetimeIndex(['2013-06-26 00:00:00+01:00', '2013-06-26 00:15:00+01:00',
               '2013-06-26 00:30:00+01:00', '2013-06-26 00:45:00+01:00',
               '2013-06-26 01:00:00+01:00', '2013-06-26 01:15:00+01:00',
               '2013-06-26 01:30:00+01:00', '2013-06-26 01:45:00+01:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns, Europe/London]', name=u'Date Time', freq=None)
```

I will like to assign to each FID the other index and obtain a multindex geodataframe. Such data frame will have a spatial index and a time series index.

How do I achieve this goal?